# Why I'm getting Error: connect ENOENT from vscode on git push origin

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm getting an error when trying to push to github from vscode terminal.

````
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-git-0e219c7318.sock'
}
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-git-0e219c7318.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-git-0e219c7318.sock'
} ``` 
This is only happening in vscode terminal cause if I use a different one I dont have this, any solution for this?
````

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had exact same problem its connection problem of VS Code restart VS code it will work fine

Comment: This problem seems to happen for me when I quit the powershell debugger session unexpectedly (using the stop debugging button), or if the interactive powershell terminal crashes.  Seems to happen pretty often.  Wish there was a way to fix it without restarting vscode.

Comment: "Restart" — the solution to 90% of all software problems. Always keeping forgetting that.

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest way to solve this is `restart` the host or docker-container.

OR, Just do like  this:

1. find your git config, eg: "~/.gitconfig"
2. remove the lines of `[credential]` from your `.gitconfig`, which looks like:

```
[credential]
        helper = "!f() { /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4414/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-998c6993-75d2-4dc0-a0a6-ccfd2b34da36.js git-credential-helper $*; }; f"
```

3. Retry to `git push/pull` now.

---

4. If still failed, you should go farther.
5. run `env | grep "vscode" | grep "git"`,  it shows
   like that:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4414/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh
VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE=/tmp/vscode-git-92516fcd1c.sock
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN=/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/bin/4414/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js
```

6. Restore your environment variables, make it naive.

```
git config credential.helper store
unset GIT_ASKPASS
unset VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE
unset VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN
```

Now, turn back to git push/pull with terminal shell.
It works now :)

[image: git pull with terminal shell]

Answer (score 0):

Try it later, I think it's an error conection, it happened to me. I wait a couple of minutes and I could push.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of VSC have a look at [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107024). Try to push from console instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if there are any people that have came here with the same issue. For me at least I found out that this can also occur when you have files with the same name. So I would also encourage you to look for duplicate file names or something else that is a bit out of wack since it might help! best of luck